# Displaying SHOM WMS in Folium / Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, wms, folium

I'm trying to display this WMS in Leaflet / Folium: http://services.data.shom.fr/INSPIRE/wms/r

I use the following code:

```
import folium


center=[49.9765229931438, 1.1902348134956244]

def inline_map(m, width=800, height=500):
    """Takes a folium instance and embed HTML."""
    m._build_map()
    srcdoc = m.HTML.replace('"', '&quot;')
    embed = HTML('<iframe srcdoc="{}" '
                 'style="width: {}px; height: {}px; '
                 'border: none"></iframe>'.format(srcdoc, width, height))
    return embed

width, height = 1400, 800

#tileset = r'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'

tileset = r'http://services.data.shom.fr/INSPIRE/wms/r/{z}/{y}/{x}'


map = folium.Map(location=center, zoom_start=10,
                    #tiles='Stamen Terrain',
                    tiles = tileset,
                    #tiles='OpenStreetMap', 
                    width=width,
                    height=height,
                    attr="MyDataAttribution")

map.save("mapTEST.html")
```

When I open mapTEST.html with my brother it does create a leaflet map object, but no tile is displayed, when I use another WMS, it works perfectly. Did I do something wrong with the URL?

Comment: `when I use another WMS, it works perfectly.` Do you mean the ArcGIS example in your code, when you reference `WMS` in that statement?  If so you should note that the ArcGIS service is not a WMS.  For a WMS you do not specify a tile set using x,y,z coordinates, instead you give a bounding box and image size.

Answer (score 2):

From the information I can find at the [portal home page](http://www.shom.fr/les-services-en-ligne/portail-datashomfr/) the data is provided as a WMS and WMTS layer. Looking at the [GetCapabilities](http://services.data.shom.fr/clevisu/wmts?Service=WMTS&Request=GetCapabilities&Version=1.0.0) shows that it only supports KVP requests while you seem to be trying to access the data as an XYZ layer.

So a request like `http://services.data.shom.fr/clevisu/wmts?layer=SCAN-LITTO_PYR-PNG_WLD_3857_WMTS&style=normal&tilematrixset=3857&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=14&TileCol=8002&TileRow=5688` will give you an image:

[image]

Alternatively you can use a WMS request from the [capabilities](http://services.data.shom.fr/INSPIRE/wms/r?Service=WMS&Request=GetCapabilities&Version=1.0.0) given.